# Swift how can I initialize function to improve performance

Tags: swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, swift4

I have finally figured out how to create a GestureRecognizer inside a UITableViewCell and attach it to a UILabel to change the contents on tap. I however have 2 concerns about my code and that is that I am creating an extra reference to a UITableView inside the UITableViewCell and that I have the addGestureRecognizer inside the UITableViewCell as well. Since the UITableViewCell is called on many times then I would like to find someway to only call the addGestureRecognizer and UITableViewCell reference once if possible this is my code ...

```
class HomeProfilePlacesCell: NSObject {

    var TableSoure: UITableView?

    @objc func PostTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)  {

        let superview = getCellForView(view: sender.view!)
        let indexpath = TableSoure!.indexPath(for: superview!)

        let cell = TableSoure!.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! HomeTVC
        cell.post.text = "Changed Content"
    }

    func HomeProfilePlaceTVC(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, streamsModel : streamModel,HOMEPROFILE: HomeProfile, controller: UIViewController) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomeTVC

        cell.post.text = streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.post.tag = indexPath.row

        // This code below gets called many times
        // I would like to call it only once for performance reasons 

        TableSoure = tableView
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PostTap(_:)))
        tapGesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

        cell.post.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Again my code is working the way I want it however I just simply want to find a way to call the GestureRecognizer and TableView reference only once.

Comment: If you *desire*  the tap gesture for each *specific displayed* cell, you've done it right. Remember, a `UITableView` is *made* for performance. Period. If you have 15,000,000 cells (and yes, I'm being faciitious) but only 10 cells are displayed... you are clearly *not* processing 15,000,000 memory allocations! IIf you wish to apply a tap gesture to the table - then do it. Of course, you'll have to wade through a 15,000,000 array if that's what being displayed....

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing, and I suspect over-complicated. The normal way to implement a custom cell is to make a UITableViewCell subclass. This seems to be "almost" a UITableViewCell subclass that is also doing some table view work. You probably want to start with the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) to make sure you're using the pieces correctly.

When you do that, then the cell won't need a link to the tableview.

About adding the gesture recognizer, you're absolutely correct that this code is creating too many recognizers. `cellForRow(at:)` is responsible for configuring cells. It should not add new elements to them, since cell are reused.

The typical solution is to add the recognizer wherever you create the cell. I expect that you're creating this cell in Interface Builder. You can add the gesture recognizers there. Look in the object library:

[image]

You can configure the action and delegate there.

(Unrelated note, functions and variables in Swift should have a leading lowercase. Leading capitals means its a type.)